# VBscript anomalies

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Why does the following **work** in VBScript (classic ASP)

```
Dim y: y = rs("file_description")
Dim x: x = (instr(y, "Internal Server Error") <> 0 or instr(y, "Server Unavailable") <> 0) AND instr(y, "RetryCount=9") = 0
```

But this **does not work**. It halts execution (without an error number or description!)

```
dim x: x = (instr(rs("file_description"), "Internal Server Error") <> 0 or instr(rs("file_description"), "Server Unavailable") <> 0) AND instr(rs("file_description"), "RetryCount=9") = 0
```

Seems strange that simply extracting the `rs("file_description")` expression into a variable causes the code to work.

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

`rs("file_description")` can mean the field object **or** its default property .Value. VBScript picks one or another depending on the context. Because

```
y = rs("file_description")
```

does **not** use `Set`, y will contain the .Value. To make things clear for the second aproach, use

```
x = (instr(rs("file_description").Value, ...
```